# Unable to Pass parameters to a visual force page as PDF in queueable class

Tags: visualforce, pdf, queueable

I am trying to pass variables to visual force page PDF that I generate using blob in the controller which gets its variable values from the queueable class. I am required to create 1000s of PDFs per update.

The issue is whenever I generate PDFs, the values for the variables are blank where it is suppose get the values from the class. I debugged my code, the variables do have the values in them but for some reason they aren't being passed to the PDFs.

**VF page Controller**

```
public with sharing class TestPageController {
    
    public Id recId{get;set;} 
    list<TestPageWrapper> response;    
    public Integer id {get;set;}  
    public Double costPrice {get;set;} 
    public String borrowerUniqueRef {get;set;}
 
    public void pdfDoc ( TestPageWrapper resp) 
    {
        if(resp != null )
        {
            id = resp.id;
            costPrice = resp.costPrice;
            borrowerUniqueRef = resp.borrowerUniqueRef;
        }

        PageReference pdf = Page.TestContractPage;
        pdf.getParameters().put('id',recId);
        pdf.getParameters().put('borrowerUniqueRef', borrowerUniqueRef);
        pdf.getParameters().put('costPrice', string.valueof(costPrice));
        
        system.debug('recID: ' + recId);
        system.debug('response in controler ======> ' + resp);
        system.debug('costPrice: ' + costPrice);
        
        Blob body;
        system.debug('after blob');
        try 
        {
            body = pdf.getContentAsPDF();
            system.debug('body pdf =>> ' + body);
            system.debug('costPrice in try: ' + costPrice);
        } 
        catch (VisualforceException e)
        {
            body = Blob.valueOf('pdf Get Failed');
            system.debug('Exception: ' + body);
            throw e;
        }
        
        ContentVersion c = new ContentVersion();
        c.Title = 'Test Contract Page-ID: ' + resp.id;
        c.PathOnclient = 'Test Contract Page.pdf';
        c.VersionData = body;
        insert c;
        system.debug('inserted cv');
        List<ContentVersion> vList = [Select id, VersionData, ContentDocumentID from ContentVersion where id =: c.id limit 1 ];
        System.debug('vList: '+vList);
        ContentDocumentLink cl = new ContentDocumentLink();
        if(vList.size() > 0)
        {
            system.debug('adding cdl');
            cl.ContentDocumentId = vList[0].ContentDocumentID;
            cl.LinkedEntityId = recId;
            cl.ShareType = 'I';
            cl.Visibility = 'AllUsers';
            system.debug('cdl: '+cl);
            insert cl;
            system.debug('inserted cdl');
        }
    }
}
```

**VF Page**

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" extensions="TestPageController">
   <span> Unique Ref: <apex:outputtext value="{!borrowerUniqueRef}"/></span>
   <span> Cost Price: <apex:outputtext value="{!costPrice}" /></span>
</apex:page>
```

**Queueable Class**

```
Public class AsyncExecution implements System.Queueable, Database.AllowsCallouts  {

Private TestPageWrapper response;
Private String recordId; 

public Integer id {get;set;}  
public Double costPrice {get;set;}
public String borrowerUniqueRef {get;set;} 


public AsyncExecution(TestPageWrapper response, String recordId) 
{
    this.response = response; 
    system.debug('Response in queueable: ' + response);
    this.recordId = recordId;
}

public void execute(QueueableContext context) 
{
    system.debug('asyn--- > response + recordId  ==>  '+ recordId + response);
    
    Opportunity newOpp = new Opportunity();
    newOpp = [SELECT ID FROM Opportunity WHERE id =: recordId];
    ApexPages.StandardController controller = new ApexPages.standardController(newOpp);
    TestPageController mpc = new TestPageController(controller); 
    mpc.pdfDoc(response);
 }
}
```

**Wrapper Class**

```
public class TestPageWrapper {
    public Integer id {get;set;} 
    public Double costPrice {get;set;}
    public String borrowerUniqueRef {get;set;} 
    
}
```

**Trigger**

```
for(Opportunity a: Trigger.new)
    {
        if(a.PostResponse__c != NULL && a.PostResponse__c != trigger.oldmap.get(a.id).PostResponse__c && a.id == '0067E00000Ge2szQAB')
        {                
            system.debug('trigger pdf');
            
            Opportunity newOpp = new Opportunity();
            newOpp = [SELECT ID FROM Opportunity WHERE id =: a.Id];
            ApexPages.StandardController controller = new ApexPages.standardController(newOpp);
            TestPageController mpc = new TestPageController(controller);
            
            list<TestPageWrapper> response;
            response = (List<TestPageWrapper>) System.JSON.deserialize(a.PostResponse__c, List<TestPageWrapper>.class);
    
            for(TestPageWrapper mcpw: response)
            {          
                if(mcpw != null )
                {
                    System.enqueueJob(new AsyncExecution(mcpw,a.id));
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: try making the controller `Private TestPageWrapper response;` as `Public TestPageWrapper response;`

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work. Wrapper class was already receiving the data and passed it to the controller. The PDF is still blank.